# How to write to file using fwrite?

Tags: c++, file, fwrite, c++98

I am new in C++ 98 .I want to write to **FILE** data type in C++ using netbeans 8.0. Here is my code that show that **load** the data in form

Here is the **main.cpp**

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <newForm.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        newForm *a = new newForm();
        a->show();
        return app.exec();
    }
    
    #include "newForm.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    
    #define MAX 128
    int i, n = 2;
    
    char str[50], Name[50], Class[50], Grade[50], Section[50], Number[50], Total[50], var1[50], var2[50];
    FILE *fptr;
    int count = 0;
    
    newForm::newForm() {
        widget.setupUi(this);
        connect(widget.pushButton_1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(Load()));
        connect(widget.pushButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(Update()));
    }
    
    void newForm::Load() {
        fptr = fopen("/root/Desktop/simple.conf", "r");
    
        if (fptr == NULL) {
            printf("Could not open file");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (EOF == fscanf(fptr, "%s", var1)) {
                break;
            }
    
            if (EOF == fscanf(fptr, "%s", var2)) {
                break;
            }
    
            if (strcmp(var2, "Name") == 0) {
                sprintf(Name, "%s", var1);
                widget.lineEdit_1->setText(QString::fromStdString(Name));
            }
            if (strcmp(var2, "Class") == 0) {
                sprintf(Class, "%s", var1);
                widget.lineEdit_2->setText(QString::fromStdString(Class));
            }
            if (strcmp(var2, "Section") == 0) {
                sprintf(Section, "%s", var1);
                widget.lineEdit_3->setText(QString::fromStdString(Section));
            }      
            if (strcmp(var2, "Number") == 0) {
                sprintf(Number, "%s", var1);
                widget.lineEdit_4->setText(QString::fromStdString(Number));
            } 
            if (strcmp(var2, "Total") == 0) {
                sprintf(Total, "%s", var1);
                widget.lineEdit_5->setText(QString::fromStdString(Total));
            }
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZwnE.png)

Here is my code for updating the form

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#include <stdio.h>

const int StrSize = 49;
typedef char textStr[StrSize + 1];

void newForm::Update(){
    fptr = fopen("/root/Desktop/simple.conf","r" );
    textStr str,name,section,number,class1,total,grade,var1,var2;    
   
    strcpy(name,     widget.lineEdit_1->text().toLocal8Bit());
    strcpy(class1,   widget.lineEdit_2->text().toLocal8Bit());   
    strcpy(section, widget.lineEdit_3->text().toLocal8Bit());
    strcpy(number,  widget.lineEdit_4->text().toLocal8Bit());
    strcpy(total,   widget.lineEdit_5->text().toLocal8Bit());

    const char * text = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if( EOF == fscanf(fptr, "%s", var1)){
            break;
        }

        if( EOF == fscanf(fptr, "%s", var2)){
            break;
        }
        const char * text = NULL;
        if(strcmp(var2,"Name") == 0){
           fwrite(name, sizeof(name) , sizeof(name) , fptr);
        }
        if(strcmp(var2,"Class") == 0){                      
            fwrite(class1, sizeof(class1) , sizeof(class1) , fptr);
        }if(strcmp(var2,"Name") == 0){
           fwrite(section, sizeof(section) , sizeof(section) , fptr);
        }
        if(strcmp(var2,"Section") == 0){                      
            fwrite(class1, sizeof(class1) , sizeof(class1) , fptr);
        }
        if(strcmp(var2,"Number") == 0){
            fwrite(grade, sizeof(grade) , sizeof(grade) , fptr);
        }
        if(strcmp(var2,"Total") == 0){
            fwrite(grade, sizeof(grade) , sizeof(grade) , fptr);
        }
        else if((strcmp(var2, "Name") != 0)  &&  (strcmp(var2, "Class") != 0)  &&  (strcmp(var2, "Grade") != 0) && strcmp(var2,"Number") !=0 && strcmp(var2,"Total") != 0) {
            fwrite(var1, sizeof(var1) , sizeof(var1) , fptr);
        }       
    }    
    fclose(fptr);

}
```

It  is not writing **string,IP,float** and int at all ? How to make it write thw this text file ?

**simple.conf**

```
AAA     Name
192.168.9.33    Class
A10     Section
72.777      Number
100     Total
```

Comment: If you want to write a text file, you don't use fwrite.

Comment: Side note: [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is a no, no, no go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h?r=Saves_AllUserSaves)

Comment: use fprintf to write text to a file

Comment: also why use a 25 year old c++. And why not use c++ streams. And std::string too?

Comment: For c++ `std::ofstream` is the preferable way.

Comment: Do you know what opening the file in `"r"` mode means?

Comment: "I am new in C++ 98" - that's an interesting one... joined that party a bit too late, huh?  :-P

Comment: @pm100 Because 25 year old C++ performs as fast as C++23 and it has much less complexity. Sometimes like in high frequency trading those requirements are a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to updating the file is dangerous and confusing. You should update the file completely, rewriting it from scratch.

First, you need to open the file for writing instead of reading. When you issue an `fopen(...,"w");` it will truncate the file to zero length for you so you don't need to care about resizing it.

Then you can just use `fprintf()` instead of `fwrite()` to deal better with text outputs, like in the example below.

Note that I have NOT compiled the example below and the actual format you presented is actually confusing so adapt to it.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

static void writeField( FILE* f, const char* name, const char* value ) {
    fprintf( f, "%s,%s\n", name, value );
}

void newForm::Update(){
    const char* filename = "/root/Desktop/simple.conf";
    FILE* fptr = fopen( filename,"w" );
    writeField( fptr, "Name",    widget.lineEdit_1->text().toLocal8Bit());
    writeField( fptr, "Class",   widget.lineEdit_2->text().toLocal8Bit());   
    writeField( fptr, "Section", widget.lineEdit_3->text().toLocal8Bit());
    writeField( fptr, "Number",  widget.lineEdit_4->text().toLocal8Bit());
    writeField( fptr, "Total",   widget.lineEdit_5->text().toLocal8Bit());

    fclose(fptr);
}
```